# Why does my extended PUG dont use Bootstrap?

Tags: pug

i have a problem with my bootstrap/PUG Code. The Problem is,that my Bootstrap does not function in only this .pug file? Every other file is fine.Does somebody know what's wrong?

Those are my codes:
first the Js code.It functioned when i haven't linked the database in my code, but since i have used the databank, bootstrap won't work anymore.

```
//Detailsrender
app.get('/Details/:id', (req, res) => {
  var weatherinfoId = req.params.id;
 
      dbClient.query("SELECT * FROM weatherinformation JOIN weatherstation ON weatherstation.id = weatherinformation.station_id WHERE station_id=$1",[weatherinfoId],
        function (dbError, dbResponse){
          res.render("details",{
            weatherinformation: dbResponse.rows[0]
          });

        });
        
    });
```

Secondly the layout.pug file:

```
doctype html
html 

    head
        charset(utf-8)
        block title
        link(rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css")
        link(rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css")
body
    header.p-3.bg-dark.text-white
        .container
            .d-flex.flex-wrap.align-items-center.justify-content-center.justify-content-lg-start
                a.d-flex.align-items-center.mb-2.mb-lg-0.text-white.text-decoration-none(href='/')
                    svg.bi.me-2(width='40' height='32' role='img' aria-label='Bootstrap')
                        use(xlink:href='#bootstrap')
                ul.nav.col-12.col-lg-auto.me-lg-auto.mb-2.justify-content-center.mb-md-0
                    li
                        a.nav-link.px-2.text-secondary(href='/Weathertop') Weathertop
                    li
                        a.nav-link.px-2.text-white(href='/Dashboard') Dashboard
block content
```

And lastly the Details.pug file

```
extends layout.pug

block title 
    title #{weatherinformation.station}

block content  
    .row
        // First Card 
        .col-xl-3.col-md-6.mb-4
          .card.border-left-warning.shadow.h-100.py-2
             .card-body
                .col.mr-2
                    .dashboard_text #{weatherinformation.station}
        // Second Card
        .col-xl-3.col-md-6.mb-4
            .card.border-left-warning.shadow.h-100.py-2
              .card-body
                .col.mr-2
                    .dashboard_text Wetter
                    .h5.mb-0.mr-3.font-weight-bold.text-white-800 #{weatherinformation.weather}
                .col-auto
                    i.fas.fa-dollar-sign.fa-2x.text-gray-300
        // Third Card
        .col-xl-3.col-md-6.mb-4
            .card.border-left-warning.shadow.h-100.py-2
             .card-body
                .col.mr-2
                    .dashboard_text Temperatur
                    
                    .col-auto
                        .h5.mb-0.mr-3.font-weight-bold.text-white-800 #{weatherinformation.temperature} Grad
                    
        // Forth Card
        .col-xl-3.col-md-6.mb-4
            .card.border-left-warning.shadow.h-100.py-2
             .card-body
                .col.mr-2
                    .dashboard_text Wind
                    .h5.mb-0.mr-3.font-weight-bold.text-white-800 #{weatherinformation.wind} bft
                .col-auto
                    i.fas.fa-comments.fa-2x.text-gray-300
        // Fifth Card            
        .col-xl-3.col-md-6.mb-4
            .card.border-left-warning.shadow.h-100.py-2
             .card-body
                .col.mr-2
                    .dashboard_text Luftdruck
                    .h5.mb-0.mr-3.font-weight-bold.text-white-800 #{weatherinformation.air} hpa
                .col-auto
                    i.fas.fa-comments.fa-2x.text-gray-300
```

Help would be appreciated

Comment: So i found out that the in my console the error 

Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/Details/css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

triggers.But idk how to fix it

Comment: Is your indenting correct on the layouts page (hard to tell from the pasted code).

Comment: OMG thats it thank you very much!